# Setting Lambda to POST on API Gateway Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, boto3

I am trying to set a lambda endpoint to my api gateway using boto3. I am using the method `put_integration` as described in the API Gateway boto3 docs. I have set a POST method successfully but I am not able to integrate the lambda. In particular, I am having trouble finding the naming of the `uri` parameter. I have my accountID, regionName, and functionName, but I dont know how to correctly format this parameter

```
 botoKwargs = {
    'restApiId' : api_id,
    'resourceId' : resource_id,
    'httpMethod' : 'POST',
    'type' : 'AWS',
    'integrationHttpMethod' : 'POST',
    'uri' : uri,
    # 'credentials' : credentials,
}
apig_client = get_apig_client()
apig_client.put_integration(**botoKwargs)
```

I am certain that this is the only problem. I can't find a canonical method of setting the `uri` parameter. The following excerpt is relevant:

```
For AWS or AWS_PROXY integrations, the URI is of the form arn:aws:apigateway:{region}:{subdomain.service|service}:path|action/{service_api} . Here, {Region} is the API Gateway region (e.g., us-east-1 ); {service} is the name of the integrated AWS service (e.g., s3 ); and {subdomain} is a designated subdomain supported by certain AWS service for fast host-name lookup. action can be used for an AWS service action-based API, using an Action={name}&{p1}={v1}&p2={v2}... query string. The ensuing {service_api} refers to a supported action {name} plus any required input parameters. Alternatively, path can be used for an AWS service path-based API. The ensuing service_api refers to the path to an AWS service resource, including the region of the integrated AWS service, if applicable. For example, for integration with the S3 API of `GetObject <https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html>`__ , the uri can be either arn:aws:apigateway:us-west-2:s3:action/GetObject&Bucket={bucket}&Key={key} or arn:aws:apigateway:us-west-2:s3:path/{bucket}/{key}
```

url is here:

```
 https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.put_integration
```

when I give the lambda arn I get the error

```
AWS ARN for integration must contain path or action
```

I would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Here is a relevant GitHub issue https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/572

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integration-request-basic-setup.html) documentation, the uri should be like

```
arn:aws:apigateway:api-region:lambda:path//2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:lambda-region:account-id:function:lambda-function-name/invocations
```

Note: You have to change ***api-region***, ***lambda-region***, **account-id** and ***lambda-function-name*** with your data.